# Unable to load R package gsl: libgsl.so.25: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory

Tags: r, r-package

My R version is 4.1.2. It seems that I successfully install gsl package, but when I run `library(gsl)`, I get following error:

```
Error: package or namespace load failed for ‘energy’ in dyn.load(file, DLLpath = DLLpath, ...):
 unable to load shared object '/public/home/username/localR/lib64/R/library/gsl/libs/gsl.so':
  libgsl.so.25: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory
```

Only this package has the error above. Meanwhile, when I try to use the packages related to it(e.x. energy), R will occur the same error. However, other packages are not affected.

Thanks.

Comment: Welcome to Stackoverflow. What is the result of `gsl-config --version` in your terminal (not in R)? This is just to check that the underlying, required libgsl.25,so, (or 26) is installed so that `gsl` package can find it when installed from CRAN. If this doesn't return something like `2.5` or `2.6`, you need to install the Gnu Scientific Library then gsl.

Comment: You can do `whereis gsl` e.g. in Bash to see where the shared object actually is. It must be somewhere else than `/public/home/username/localR/lib64/R/library/gsl/libs/gsl.so`

Comment: The result of  `gsl-config --version` is `2.6`. When I do `whereis gsl`, it returns `/usr/include/gsl`. What should I do after I know the shared object actually is? Thanks.